# Variance of sum of random variables (ASM exam P)

Tags: probability, actuarial-science, variance

This is a problem from Dr. Ostaszewski's actuarial exam P ASM manual. It states:

An automobile insurance company divides its policyholders into two groups: good drivers and bad drivers. For the good drivers, the amount of an average claim is 1400, with a variance of 40,000. For the bad drivers, the amount of an average claim is 2000, with a variance of 250,000. 60% of the policyholders are classified as good drivers. Calculate the variance of the amount of claim for a policyholder.

The solution states that the distribution of the random amount of the claim X can be viewed as a mixture of two weighted distributions. Then, it finds the variance of X using the variance formula $Var(X) = E[X^{2}] - E[X]^{2}$

$E[X] = 0.6\cdot E[X_{1}] + 0.4\cdot E[X_{2}] = 0.6\cdot1400 +0.4\cdot2000 = 1640$

This is fine to me. But my problem is with the next step, where the solution states

$E[X^{2}] = 0.6\cdot E[X_{1}^{2}] + 0.4\cdot E[X_{2}^{2}] $

I am confused because shouldn't $X^{2} = (0.6\cdot X_{1} +0.4\cdot X_{2})^{2}$? Why is it that in finding the second moment of X, we only square the random variables?

Thank you!

Edit: Deleted "$X = 0.6X_{1} + 0.4X_{2}$" from the solution. It is not part of the provided solutions. I typed it in on accident!

Comment: **tl;dr** No, because $X$ is *not* a linear combination of the two variables. $X_1$ is the measure of the claim under condition that the driver is good.   $X_2$ that under condition of the driver being bad.  $X$ is the unconditional measure.

Comment: Thank you for the correction! Yes it turns out I misunderstood. The part involving the linear combination is an unwritten step that I (incorrectly) deduced from the author's solution. I was thinking of in terms of proportions, but like heropup said, they must fall into one category or the other, instead of having "60% of the bad trait, 40% of the good"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important--especially in the context of the exam--to step back and think about what it means to calculate the variance in the claim amount for a randomly selected policyholder.  Note here that a given policyholder can either only be "good" or "bad":  there are no individual policyholders that are a mixture of $60\%$ "good" and $40\%$ "bad."  Once you randomly choose a policyholder, they are a member of exactly one of the two driver categories.

Therefore, it makes no sense to define a random variable that models the claim amount as a linear combination of the random claim amounts for each group.  What we actually have here is an example of a **hierarchical model**; that is to say, there is a second random variable, say $Y$, that models whether a randomly selected policyholder is "good" or "bad," and **conditional** on this random variable, the claim amount has a particular distribution.  More formally, let $Y \sim \operatorname{Bernoulli}(p = 0.6)$, so that $Y = 1$ is the outcome that a randomly chosen policyholder is "good."  Then, with $X$ being the claim amount as before, we have $$\operatorname{E}[X \mid Y = 1] = 1400, \quad \operatorname{Var}[X \mid Y = 1] = 40000; \\ \operatorname{E}[X \mid Y = 0] = 2000, \quad \operatorname{Var}[X \mid Y = 0] = 250000.$$  We are then asked to determine $$\operatorname{Var}[X],$$ the **unconditional** variance of the claim amount of a randomly selected policyholder.  To this end, $$\operatorname{E}[X^2 \mid Y] = \operatorname{Var}[X \mid Y] + \operatorname{E}[X \mid Y]^2,$$ so we compute $$\operatorname{E}[X^2 \mid Y = 1] = 40000 + 1400^2 = 2 \times 10^6, \\ \operatorname{E}[X^2 \mid Y = 0] = 250000 + 2000^2 = 4.25 \times 10^6. $$  Then by the **law of total expectation**,  $$\begin{align*} \operatorname{E}[X^2] &= \operatorname{E}[X^2 \mid Y = 0] \Pr[Y = 0] + \operatorname{E}[X^2 \mid Y = 1] \Pr[Y = 1] \\ &= (2(0.6) + 4.25(0.4)) \times 10^6 \\ &= 2.9 \times 10^6, \end{align*}$$ and the rest is straightforward.

Why did we have to go through the second moment rather than compute the total variance directly?  This is because it is **not** generally true that $$\operatorname{Var}[X] = \operatorname{E}[\operatorname{Var}[X \mid Y]].$$  Instead, the **law of total variance** is $$\operatorname{Var}[X] = \operatorname{E}[\operatorname{Var}[X \mid Y]] + \operatorname{Var}[\operatorname{E}[X \mid Y]].$$  You *could* use this formula to calculate the result, but it is essentially no different than what we've done above.

Answer (score 1):

No, $X$ is not a linear combination of the conditioned random variables.   $X\neq 0.6 X_1 + 0.4 X_2$

Your text is just using the notational shorthand: $~\mathsf E(X_i) = \mathsf E(X\mid C_i)~$, $~\mathsf E(X^2_i)=\mathsf E(X^2\mid C_i)~$, $~\mathsf{Var}(X_i)=\mathsf{Var}(X\mid C_i)~$.   Where, we let $C_i$ be the *event* that a driver is in category-$i$; in this case category-1 is "good drivers", et cetera.   Then the *Law of Total Expectation* states:

$$\mathsf E(g(X)) ~=~ \mathsf P(C_1)~\mathsf E(g(X)\mid C_1)+\mathsf P(C_2)~\mathsf E(g(X)\mid C_2)$$

So here we have:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(X) ~=~& 0.6~\mathsf E(X\mid C_1)+0.4~\mathsf E(X\mid C_2)
\\[1ex] =~& 0.6~\mathsf E(X_1)+0.4~\mathsf E(X_2)
\\[2ex] \mathsf E(X^2) ~=~& 0.6~\mathsf E(X^2\mid C_1)+0.4~\mathsf E(X^2\mid C_2)
\\ ~=~& 0.6~\mathsf E(X_1^2)+0.4~\mathsf E(X_2^2)
\\ ~=~& 0.6~\big(\mathsf {Var}(X_1)+\mathsf E(X_1)^2\big) + 0.4~\big(\mathsf {Var}(X_2)+\mathsf E(X_2)^2\big) 
\end{align}$$

Put them together to find $\mathsf {Var}(X)$.

$\Box$

---

**tl;dr** No, because $X$ is *not* a linear combination of the two variables. $X_1$ is the measure of a claim under condition that the driver is good.   $X_2$ that under condition of the driver being bad.   $X$ is the unconditional measure, which is *not* the weighted sum of the conditional measures.   $X\neq 0.6 X_1 + 0.4 X_2$

$\blacksquare$

Comment: In the last line of $E(X^2)$, is it $Var(X_1)-E(X_1)^2$ or $Var(X_1)+E(X_1)^2$?  (Respectively, $X_2$.)